# Don't read between the lines, read behind them!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

People find me against them in all walks of life,
I'm there at their lowest, causing them strife.
Some choose to love me, others, to hate me,
Others, to fight me, others, escape me.
Many discover, much to their shame,
That themselves and I are one and the same.
Few can defeat me without seeking help,
Oftentimes coming from the me of myself.
The wisest, however, have nothing to fear,
For if you've made the right choices, I'm already near.
What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are

> **an enemy.**

People find me against them in all walks of life,

> People from all walks of life make or **[have enemies](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/w/winstonchu135210.html)** ...

I'm there at their lowest, causing them strife.

> ... who are there to cause trouble for them, often **[when they're down.](https://cdn.meme.am/cache/instances/folder567/33953567.jpg)**

Some choose to love me, others, to hate me,
Others, to fight me, others, escape me.

> hate: [You have heard that it was said, 'Love your neighbor and **hate your enemy**.' <sub>Matthew 5:43</sub>](http://biblehub.com/matthew/5-43.htm);
>  love: [But I tell you, **love your enemies** and pray for those who persecute you <sub>Matthew 5:44</sub>](http://biblehub.com/matthew/5-44.htm);
>  fight: In battle, you fight - sometimes **[to win](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nINmdswpbE&t=13)**, sometimes **[not](http://www.salon.com/2017/03/01/trumps-we-dont-fight-to-win-line-has-upset-veterans/)**?
>  escape: You may find that you need to **[fight and run away](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214999/for-he-that-fights-and-runs-away-may-live-to-fight-another-day-wisdom-or-moc)**.

Many discover, much to their shame,
That themselves and I are one and the same.

> **[We have met the enemy, and he is us](http://www.thisdayinquotes.com/2011/04/we-have-met-enemy-and-he-is-us.html)**;  more generally, though, we often despise our enemies because they mirror back to us our own worst traits.

Few can defeat me without seeking help,

> It's not uncommon to **[need allies](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/1062059-there-is-only-one-thing-worse-than-fighting-with-allies)** to fight one's enemies, be they literal or figurative

Oftentimes coming from the me of myself.

> **[The enemy of my enemy is my friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_enemy_of_my_enemy_is_my_friend)**

The wisest, however, have nothing to fear,
For if you've made the right choices, I'm already near.

> **[Keep your friends close, and your enemies closer.](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/36994.html)**

Title:

> Your enemies are the ones behind where the **[battle lines are drawn.](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/500469-the-battle-lines-are-drawn-priyatama-the-more-formidable-the)**
>  (Or, less quotably but no less relevantly, a reference to **[behind enemy lines](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0159273/)**. Peer pressure :) )

Comment: *Behind the enemy lines*

Comment: You got it. Excellent work!

Comment: @Techidiot believe it or not, it's remarkably hard to find a relevant quote I liked for that word (thanks to some [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0159273/)).  I think I conveyed the idea without using it. :)